# rift sawn and quarter sawn tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I know we have tags for [rift-sawn](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rift-sawn) and [quarter-sawn](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quarter-sawn). After much research and asking/answering question here it seems easy to conclude that rift sawn milling and rift sawn wood represent two different things these days. Same goes for quarter sawn.

Recently I [rejected a tag edit](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/641) for [rift-sawn](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rift-sawn). The basis for it was the tag does not distinguish between the milling process and the resulting lumber.

---

I think we need to do something to remove the ambiguity of the sawn tags listed above by making milling and wood tags for each. For example:

[quarter-sawn-milling](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quarter-sawn-milling) and [rift-sawn-milling](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rift-sawn-milling) for the process to create them.

[quarter-sawn-wood](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quarter-sawn-wood) and [rift-sawn-wood](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rift-sawn-wood) for the wood created by the above processes.

If we were to follow such tags then the plain ones would be removed.

The above tags are mostly suggestion to spark debate. I think something should done so as we don't create problems later.

Comment: It seems to me that this would help address the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I like making this distinction. However, [quarter-sawn-milling](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quarter-sawn-milling) seems like incorrect English. I think the proper tag names would be [quarter-sawing](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quarter-sawing) and [quarter-sawn-wood](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quarter-sawn-wood) (or possibly [quarter-sawn-lumber](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quarter-sawn-lumber)).

[quarter-sawing](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quarter-sawing) is not as clear as [quarter-sawn-milling](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quarter-sawn-milling) so if we go with the former, the tags' wikis will need to emphasize the distinction between the two sets of tags.